# How can I make it so that at any point during my function the user can type "reset" and it will take them back to the beginning of my function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, javascript-scope

```
let level = 0;
let usersName;
let path;

const getBotReply = (msg) => {

    if (level === 0) {
        level = 1;
        usersName = msg;
        return "Chur " + usersName + ". Do you live in Raglan?";
    }

    if (level === 1) {
        level = 2;
        if (msg === "yes") {
        path = "left-yes";
        return "Do you know how to surf?";
    }

        if (msg === "no") {
        path = "right-no";
        return "Are you from Auckland?";
    }
}
```

Basically I want it so that instead of typing yes or no. The user will type reset and it will return to "level 0"

I've tried:

```
    if (msg === "reset") {
    level = 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of the code you're trying that is not working? Use jsfiddle or codesandbox or something like them.

Answer (score 0):

in this case, I believe it would be preferable to include a while loop.

```
while(msg === "reset"){level = 0};
```

Comment: Thank you. Where would you put it though in the scope? I want it so that at any point in my chat bot the user can type reset to go back to the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

If you put your if-check for reset at the top then you have done it correctly, and you simply forgot a return in the solution you suggested?

If you don't include a return stament in the if-check the function will just continue, so it will run the next if check, which matches the level being 0 and it will assume that "reset" is the name of the user.

So if you include

```
if(msg === "reset"{
 level = 0
 return
}
```

It should work just fine, you can leave the return blank or include a message. I included a JS fiddle which is literally your code with the fixed if check: https://jsfiddle.net/5tu7c20n/

Comment: Perfect answer thanks mate!

Comment: No problem, just remember to mark the question as answered :)